# How to append array of value into tableView in iOS Swift?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, uitableview, dictionary

TableView consists with list of dynamic label and navigation bar consists of two button called up and down.

here i'm getting data from json and append to model. But i can not able to list  in tableview. Array value should be loaded to list of label.

Here is my json appended to model:

```
   [PO_PR.poItemsModel(Material: Optional("RMECC_MOB1"), Qty: Optional("2.000"), UoM: Optional("KG"), totalValue: Optional("1000.000"), Requistor: Optional(""), StorageLocation: Optional("3001"), MatGrp: Optional("00107"), valuationPrice: Optional("1000.000"), ItemCategory: Optional("0"), lineNo: Optional("00010"), UnitofPrice: Optional("1.000")),

PO_PR.poItemsModel(Material: Optional("RMECC_MOB1"), Qty: Optional("2.000"), UoM: Optional("KG"), totalValue: Optional("1000.000"), Requistor: Optional(""), StorageLocation: Optional("3001"), MatGrp: Optional("00107"), valuationPrice: Optional("1000.000"), ItemCategory: Optional("0"), lineNo: Optional("00020"), UnitofPrice: Optional("1.000"))]
```

Initially array of first index should be loaded to list of label and then when pressing down button next of array value should be loaded to list of label.

Labels in tableview will be in each cell not in a single cell.

Here is my model:

```
struct poItemsModel {

var Material       : String?
var Qty            : String?
var UoM            : String?
var totalValue     : String?
var Requistor      : String?
var StorageLocation: String?
var MatGrp         : String?
var valuationPrice : String?
var ItemCategory   : String?
var lineNo         : String?
var UnitofPrice    : String?

init(json: JSON) {

Material = json["Material"].stringValue
Qty = json["Quantity"].stringValue
UoM = json["OrderUnit"].stringValue
totalValue = json["NetPrice"].stringValue
Requistor = json["Requistor"].stringValue
StorageLocation = json["StorageLocation"].stringValue
MatGrp = json["MatGroup"].stringValue
valuationPrice = json["NetPrice"].stringValue
ItemCategory = json["ItemCat"].stringValue
lineNo = json["Item"].stringValue
UnitofPrice = json["UnitofPrice"].stringValue

}
 }
```

Here i'm appeding json data to model:

```
    func GetPoItemCount() {

      if orderNo != nil {
    // Call API
        print("orderni::\(orderNo!)")
        PoVendorListApiManager.sharedInstance.getPoListWithModel(orderString: orderNo!){ (json:JSON) in
        // return json from API
            if let results = json["d"]["results"].array {
                print("catefory::\(results)")


                for category in results {

                     self.PoItemsArray.append(poItemsModel(json: category))

                    for (key, value) in category {
                        print("keyvalue\(key)\(value)")

                        self.poItemJsonArray.append(value)
                        self.poItemKeyArray.append(key)
                        let currency = newPrItemDetailModel(key: key, value: value)
                        self.newItemDetailsArray.append(currency)

                      }

                }

                let elm = self.PoItemsArray
                let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: elm)
                for child in mirror.children  {
                    print("key: \(String(describing: child.label)), value: \(child.value)")
                }

                print("self.PoItemsArray array:::\(self.PoItemsArray)")
                print("new model array:::\(self.newItemDetailsArray)")

                DispatchQueue.main.async { 
                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                }
            }
        }
     }
   }

  }//extension
```

Here is my tableview code:

```
      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    //        PoItems = loadPoItems()
    print("count::itemArray::\(self.PoItemsArray.count)")
    return PoItemsArray.count

   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! PoItemTableViewCell

    let itemDetails = PoItemsArray[indexPath.row]
   //        for arrayData in

  //        PoItems = loadPoItems()

 //        prItem.getProperty(at: indexPath.row)

 //        cell.materials.text = PoItemsArray[0].key!
 //        cell.materialsValue.text = itemDetails[indexPath.row]



    return cell

  }
```

Here is my screenshot where i'm trying to achieve: [image]

How to load to array of first index into list of dynamic labels and when pressing down button how to load next array index of values into list of dynamic labels.

Any help much appreciated pls....

Comment: dude BTW just use codable and JSONDecoder for something like that

Comment: any sample for codable and jsondecoder for tableview

Comment: @Fattie i have struggling for past this week fully, can tell how to achieve for my code..

Answer (score 1):

## This can not be done (realistically) with a table view.  Table views are for long *lists* (a variable number) of the *same* item which can *not* change.  What you have here is a *fixed* number (9) of *totally different* items, which *do change*.

Answer 1:

***Do not use a table view for this.  It's not what a table view is for.***

Simply use a StackView for your layout - it's dead easy, and still scrolls etc.

Done.  It will take 2 minutes.

---

Answer 2:

If as an exercise you want to use a table view, which would be wrong:

To do "synced / dynamic" tables is extremely difficult.

1. You ***must*** have a custom cell class
2. The button (on the main screen) must ***signal*** in some way to ***all of the cells*** to make the change in question.

This is a broad field of enquiry, you'd have to look in to the various ways to achieve this.

Comment: thanks for suggestions.. how can i use for my code.. any sample.

Comment: i have struggling for past this week fully, can tell how to achieve for my code..

Comment: hi @PvDev.  first step.   please **explaini what you are trying to do**.  Please look at my **first sentence** at the top of this answer.  Am I correct?

Comment: how can i append model into tableview and when tapping down button load next array value.

Comment: ok I have the solution DON'T USE A TABLE VIEW FOR THIS - IT IS WRONG.  please use a STACK VIEW.  it is very very easy to do.  go for it !

Comment: do you want to **change** what is in a cell when the button is pressed ?

Comment: OK, I cannot be clearer:  you cannot use a table view for this.  You need a simple stack view!

Comment: tutorials ..  https://www.appcoda.com/learnswift/stack-views.html   https://www.raywenderlich.com/2198310-uistackview-tutorial-for-ios-introducing-stack-views